# How to get publication status using Alexa Skill Management Api

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have created an Alexa Skill using Alexa Skill Management API's.

Now using the API
`https://api.amazonalexa.com/v0/skills/{skill-id}/submit`.

This API returns success which means that my skill is submitted for 
certification.

But How to get the publication status that whether the skill is live or 
under certification.

How can I get the publication status of skill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLI to do that,

```
get-skill-status
```

Reference: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#get-model-status-subcommand